# EBNF for capturing a comma between two optional values

Tags: regex, big-o, ebnf

I have two optional values, and when both are present, a comma needs to be in between them. If one or both values are present, there *may* be a trailing comma, but if no values are present, no comma is allowed.

Valid examples:

```
(first,second,)
(first,second)
(first,)
(first)
(second,)
(second)
()
```

*Invalid* examples:

```
(first,first,)
(first,first)
(second,second,)
(second,second)
(second,first,)
(second,first)
(,first,second,)
(,first,second)
(,first,)
(,first)
(,second,)
(,second)
(,)
(,first,first,)
(,first,first)
(,second,second,)
(,second,second)
(,second,first,)
(,second,first)
```

I have EBNF code ([XML-flavored](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-notation)) that suffices, but is there a way I can simplify it? I would like to make it more readable / less repetitive.

```
tuple ::= "(" ( ( "first" | "second" | "first" "," "second" ) ","? )? ")"
```

If it’s easier to understand in regex, here’s the equivalent code, but I need a solution in EBNF.

```regex
/\(((first|second|first\,second)\,?)?\)/
```

And here’s a helpful railroad diagram:
[image: "(" ( ( "first" | "second" | "first" "," "second" ) ","? )? ")"]

This question becomes even more complex when we **abstract it to three terms**: `"first"`, `"second"`, and `"third"` are all optional, but they must appear in that order, separated by commas, with an optional trailing comma. The best I can come up with is a brute-force method:

```
"(" (("first" | "second" | "third" | "first" "," "second" | "first" "," "third" | "second" "," "third" | "first" "," "second" "," "third") ","?)? ")"
```

[image: "(" (("first" | "second" | "third" | "first" "," "second" | "first" "," "third" | "second" "," "third" | "first" "," "second" "," "third") ","?)? ")"]
Clearly, a solution involving *O(2<sup>n</sup>)* complexity is not very desirable.

Comment: If you're just using `first` and `second` what's the need for a regex?

Comment: @WJS I reduced my question to [the simplest case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In my real code, `"first"` and `"second"` are actually complex expressions. For the purposes of StackOverflow, it doesn’t matter what they are, so I made them atoms. Encapsulation FTW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to simplify it, but not by much:

```
"(" ( ("first" ("," "second")? | "second") ","? )? ")"
```

[image: "(" ( ("first" ("," "second")? | "second") ","? )? ")"]

For the **three-term solution**, take the two-term solution and prepend a first term:

```
"(" (("first" ("," ("second" ("," "third")? | "third"))? | "second" ("," "third")? | "third") ","?)? ")"
```

[image: "(" (("first" ("," ("second" ("," "third")? | "third"))? | "second" ("," "third")? | "third") ","?)? ")"]

For any (n+1)-term solution, take the n-term solution and prepend a first term. This complexity is *O(n)*, which is significantly better than *O(2<sup>n</sup>)*.

Answer (score 0):

This expression might help you to maybe design a better expression. You can do this with only using capturing groups and swipe from left to right and pass your possible inputs, maybe similar to this:

```
\((first|second|)(,|)(second|)([\)|,]+)
```

I'm just guessing that you wish to capture the middle comma:

[image]

This may not be the exact expression you want. However, it might show you how this might be done in a simple way:

```
^(?!\(,)\((first|)(,|)(second|)([\)|,]+)$
```

[image]

You can add more boundaries to the left and right of your expression, maybe similar to [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/PV4MjI/1):

[image]

This graph shows how the second expression would work:

[image]

#### Performance

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of the second expression using a simple 1-million times `for` loop, and how it captures `first` and `second` using `$1` and `$3`.

```js
repeat = 1000000;
start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 var string = "(first,second,)";
 var regex = /^(?!\(,)\((first|second|)(,|)(second|)([\)|,]+)$/gms;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$1 and $3");
}

end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that works. Wouldn't it also capture `(second,second)`? I'll add some invalid examples to my question for you to test against.

Comment: Also, which tool are you using to generate the railroad diagrams? looks pretty useful.

Comment: Apparently, you are only working with the words `first` and `second` so why don't you just match on the legitimate cases?

Comment: @Emma Ugh.  I was asking that of the OP.  I commented in the wrong section.  Perhaps I don't understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with EBNF but I am familiar with BNF and parser grammars.  The following is just a variation of what you have based on my own regex.  I am assuming the unquoted parens are not considered tokens and are used to group related elements.

```
  tuple ::= ( "(" ( "first,second" | "first" | "second" ) ","? ")" ) | "()"
```

- It matches on either `(first,second` or `(first` or `(second`
- Then it matches on an optional `,`
- Followed by a closing parens. `)`
- or the empty parens grouping. `()`

But I doubt this is an improvement.

Here is my Java test code.  The first two lines of strings in the test data match.  The others do not.

```java
      String[] testdata = {
            "(first,second,)", "(first,second)", "(first,)", "(first)",
            "(second,)", "(second)", "()",

            "(first,first,)", "(first,first)", "(second,second,)",
            "(second,second)", "(second,first,)", "(second,first)",
            "(,first,second,)", "(,first,second)", "(,first,)", "(,first)",
            "(,second,)", "(,second)", "(,)", "(,first,first,)",
            "(,first,first)", "(,second,second,)", "(,second,second)",
            "(,second,first,)", "(,second,first)"
      };

      String reg = "\\(((first,second)|first|second),?\\)|\\(\\)";
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(reg);

      for (String t : testdata) {
         Matcher m = p.matcher(t);
         if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(t);
         }
      }
```